# I want to validate the field value before submit the record edit form which is in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-components

```
<aura:component controller="EditFormTestController"
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="quoteRatePlanList" type="zqu__QuoteRatePlan__c[]"/>

    <lightning:card title="FormTest9">
        <div aura:id="recordEditForm">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.quoteRatePlanList}" var="quoteRatePlan">
                <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="{!quoteRatePlan.Id}"
                                          objectApiName="zqu__QuoteRatePlan__c">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Usage_Tenant__c"/>
                </lightning:recordEditForm>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>

        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Update" name="update" onclick="{!c.update}"/>
        </aura:set>
    </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.fetchPlans(cmp, event, helper);
    },

    update: function (cmp, event, helper) {

//**Before this code i want to validate the field values that a field is blank or not can someone help me** 

         cmp.find("editForm").forEach( form =>{ form.submit(); }) 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field is required on the database level, `lightning:recordEditForm` automatically validates it when submitted.

---

If your field is not required on the database level and still you want to make it required on this form then add `required` attribute to the `lightning:inputField`. Then the form will automatically validate the field when submitted.

```
 <lightning:inputField fieldName="Usage_Tenant__c" required="true"/>
```